# Cookies doesnt get set when sending api request sent from a subdomain

Tags: reactjs, express, subdomain

im not sure if this is a localhost issue or not but nevertheless,
I have react app running on localhost:3000 and I have a nestjs app running on localhost:4000.

The react app supports multitenancy using subdomains. When I send the API request from the main domain the cookies get set and are persisted in the browser, but when I send a request from "admin.localhost:3000" the cookie gets set but vanishes on browser refresh. I also noted that the domain for the cookie is localhost, not app.localhost. For this i tried setting the domain value in the cookie as "domain":".localhost". This doesn't work either.

This is how I'm sending the request from the frontend

```
 const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/login", {
        credentials: "include",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: email,
          password,
        }),
      });
```

Cors Config

```
  cors: {
          origin: /^(https?|http):\/\/([\da-z-]+\.)?localhost(:\d{2,5})?$/,
          credentials: true,
        },
```

Cookie setting

```
 res.cookie('access_token',mytoken, {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: true,
      domain: '.localhost',
    });
```

I've also tried without samesite and without domain, mainly just changing the setting, none of that seems to work when the request comes from the subdomain.

**I'm not looking to share cookies but for cookies related their respective domains to be set**

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in your `package.json` file in react folder

`"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",`

I think it will help❤️

Comment: This doesnt work, shouldnt be a cors issue since the request all get sent as well, like i said the cookie from the response doesn't get set